# If ultrasonic waves have such large wavelengths, then how can they be used to sense such small details?

Tags: optics, waves, acoustics, wavelength, ultrasound

We use the properties of waves for sensing. This includes electromagnetic waves, such as in lasers, but also mechanical waves, such as sound. And one of the primary factors that determine how useful a wave is for sensing is its wavelength. My understanding is that, the lower the wavelength of the wave, the greater the resolution with which it can sense, since the better it is capable of interacting with smaller and/or more particles.

I was just pondering over this and had a random thought. One of the primary reasons that lasers are utilised for high-resolution sensing is because they can reach relatively low wavelengths – say, around 400-2000 nanometers. But we also utilise ultrasonic waves for sensing that requires relatively high resolution – for instance, in medical ultrasound, to sense details of the interior of the human body. But the ultrasonic waves used in medical ultrasound are in the low MHz region, so a 1-5 MHz ultrasonic wave would have a wavelength of around 300-60 *meters*. Clearly, if we compare this wavelength to the wavelength of lasers, the wavelength of ultrasonic waves is gigantic. But then how can such large wavelengths be used to sense such relatively small details of the interior of the human body? This seems difficult to reconcile with the aforementioned wavelength-resolution principle.

Comment: The speed of ultrasound in soft tissue is usually taken to be $1540$ m/s. Since $\lambda = vT$, the wavelength is $1.54 - 7.70$ mm.

Comment: @mmesser314 Ohhh, of course; converting frequency to wavelength needs to take into account the speed, which is obviously not the speed of light for mechanical waves through a biological medium.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But the ultrasonic waves used in medical ultrasound are in the low MHz region, so a 1-5 MHz ultrasonic wave would have a wavelength of around 300-60 meters.

Ultrasound is an acoustic wave, so the appropriate velocity is the speed of sound, not the speed of light. In tissue the speed of sound is about 1500 m/s. So the wavelength is about 1 mm.

https://www.ers-education.org/lrmedia/2016/pdf/298677.pdf

Comment: Yes, I didn't bother calculating it by hand and instead used an online frequency-wavelength calculator. Silly me.